FG mounting terminals on DC converter (power supply). Do they need to be connected?
I've read similar answers/questions here which seem to indicate that the through-holes on the PCB for mounting, marked FG, are for frame-ground - in other words, is it true they should be bonded to each other? I was going to re-mount this board on isolators that would make each point not be connected, and now I'm thinking that I will have to wire some kind of eyelet jumper to go between all the FG points so they are bonded to each other. Is that true?
This is a DC power supply, taken off a newer small trailer. It was removed because the owners added a solar set-up, that included batteries, a PM3-45 power supply/charger and inverter. There was no longer any need for the basic 13.8v DC converter, to provide power to the 12v loads.
I have ripped-out the 80-watt-consuming-when-idle transformer-based power supply that was in a previous, much older trailer, and the couple donated their 'new' board to retrofit this one.
First image is the bottom/back of the board. Red arrows are marking mounting holes, that have 'FG' and a circle around them, printed around them on other side (top). '?' is a circled hole without the FG designation, but seems to be part of that FG circuit.
Second image is the top/front of the board.



The unit looks like it is intended to be mounted on an earthed metal chassis that connects all the FG mounting holes to earth.
I emphasize that the intention is to not only connect the FG terminals together but to provide earth to the FG terminals. It may also be important that all FG terminals are connected together.
So the two worst thing is to do is to isolate them and to not provide earth to the board.
If you look at the mains input wiring, it looks like the live and neutral have blue ceramic Y capacitors to the nearest FG terminal, which also looks goes to an unused pin - which means this board appears to have an option for directly mounting a mains inlet connector of some sort, like the IEC or cloverleaf type earthed mains inlets.
And the fact that there are Y caps to FG, it means the same as for every mains device with Y caps to chassis, that you cannot simply connect the FG terminals together.
The output positive and negative terminals also have Y capacitors to FG terminal near them.
Also the heat sink appears to have Y cap to FG. Only one of the FG mounting holes is electrically unconnected to the circuit.
It means that if you connect FG terminals together like they are supposed to, you also need to provide mains earth to the FG terminals.
If you don't, then the mains input Y caps will make the FG terminal capacitively coupled to half-mains voltage, and it then gets coupled via the output Y caps to the output terminals, making them also float at half-mains AC voltage.
This is usually not what you want.
So if you intend to use this for any purpose, you must have an earthed mains plug and wiring, to a metal box or at least a metal plate that gets earthed, which also earths all the FG terminals.
The heat sink is also dangerous and live so that is why there must be a metal box, or plastic enclosure if you only used an earthed metal plate.
So that supply is not intended to be used with a two-prong mains plug without earth.

I had to read what you wrote about twice.
"So the supply is not intended to be used with a two-prong mains plug without earth" which is what elicits laughter from me, because, as I remember it, this was taken out of a plastic enclosure that had the white wire you see wired to the neutral bar, and the hot wire run to a breaker - from the factory that made the trailer! SMH.
Good to know that the heatsink is live, or that like you say, having the FG ungrounded can mean the metal case this board goes in can move up to about half (60v AC) of the live voltage. Will find a metal enclosure!

Got it working! Enclosed completely. Grounded as described to earth at all (circled) FG and the circled (but not labelled FG) earth point.
Thanks!

It's hard to say without seeing a schematic. That being said if you don't want RF spewing out of the power supply, it needs to be connected.
The FG pins probably allow the power supply to be attached to a metal frame and allow for shielding around the supply. It's unlikely that they are current carrying grounds that the supply needs to rely on to function.
As far as not grounding the unit, this could be unsafe as not having a metal chassis would violate the UL certification that the unit was tested to. Faults would not be protected on the chassis, so realize that this could be unsafe to do this.

I believe it is likely. Many power supplies come with manuals that say the PCB must be connected to metal chassis, as the chassis is expected to be earthed to mains plug, which means  the mains input to a PSU gets the earth for EMI filter, and also the output gets either AC coupling for EMI or DC coupling for earth-referenced output.

Good point, I also neglected to think about saftey, for the supply to be safe it should be in the metal chassis, but I assume this will be used for hobbyist purposes.

Thank you for your comments.
This was not in a metal box. It was in a plastic housing, sandwiched between the 12v and Line side fuses/breakers, with metal screws holding it down to the plastic posts. There was a cooling fan, that if I removed it, would have left a cosmetic hole. There is a 12v pin-out for a fan, on the board, and I will be adding a fan.
What I can do, is put it in a new plastic or metal box, and if plastic, add a chain of eyelet connectors to the back, so essentially everywhere there is an anchor, on the backside it will be electrically connected.

@MTTS See my answer - I did some light reverse-engineering from tve photo and everything just screams that it should be used with earthed mains, with all FGs earthed. It may be safe to leave all FGs unconnected but we don't have the make/model and the installation manual. If it was used with non-earthed mains inlet, then I would leave FGs unconnected, but I also cannot guarantee about safety or damage to the device so it should not be used for projects where users can touch electrical parts or projects that connect to other equipment.

I ordered an aluminium box and standoffs, based on your examination.

@MTTS If used in a product and you want to pass NRTL saftey, mains level voltages need to be shielded and grounded.
